# iOS Cordova set local file as img src

Tags: ios, html, image, cordova, wkwebview

I am using Cordova File Plugin to get a file on the disk. I want to display that file in my app, so I have some javascript to do:

```
image.src = imageFile.localURL;
```

However I get an error about the url being unsupported. I think this is because of the cdvfile:// prefix?

I've also tried using the file entry:

```
imageFileEntry.nativeURL
imageFileEntry.toInternalURL()
```

But no luck. I either get an error about failing to load the local resource or that the URL is unsupported.

There are quite a few questions on Google when searching this issue but none have been able to resolve my problem. Am I missing some step? Right now I'm doing:

1. Get FileEntry
2. Create Image object
3. Set Image source to file path from file entry

Do I need to set up some kind of server on the device to host the file? Use another plugin? What might I be missing?

Relevant stuff about my setup:

- My app is using WK Webview
- I'm loading a web page in the app which loads and runs the code to display an image from the device
- The device is running iOS 10.2

Comment: What plugins do you have installed in your project (and version#s)?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone struggling as I was. For cordova-ios 6.0.0+ there is also a solution, which requires no significant change to the code which I found after hopeless days when no solution seemed available

There are 2 steps required:

First update your config.xml with following

```
<platform name="ios">    
  <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
  <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
 </platform>
```

Then convert your file:// link by using the undocumented method

```
window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(filePath)
```

This method performs the conversion into a virtual localhost link that makes the file accessible and bypasses the WkWebView restrictions. A little bit longer sample goes like this

```
let localFile = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'logo.png';
let convertedPath = window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(localFile);
document.getElementById("myImg").src = convertedPath;
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno! Just ran into this problem and with your instructions it was easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

WKWebview can only show img in `cordova.file.tempDirectory` (`file:///var/mobile/Applications/Container/Data/<GUID of app>/tmp/`), so you need copy image files to tmp directory for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the toURL() method?

Try console logging the output and ensure you are getting something like:

'file:///var/mobile.........'

I've also had problems with spaces in the URL on iOS.

Regards